# jquery sortable div drag and drop text is not editable by ckeditor

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, ckeditor, jquery-ui-sortable

I have following source code

```js
$( function() {
  $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
  }).disableSelection();
} );

InlineEditor
  .create( document.querySelector( '.editor' ) )
  .catch( error => {
    console.error( error );
  });
```

```css
#sortable1, #sortable2 {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 142px;
  min-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <body>
     
    <p class="editor">Text edited by ckeditor outer sortable can edit by ckeditor</p>
    
    
    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    </ul>
     
    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="ui-state-highlight editor">Text edited by ckeditor inside sortable can not edit by ckeditor</li>
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
    </ul>
     
     
    </body>
    </html>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/17.0.0/inline/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

This connected sortable drag and drop list build by jquery ui. I would like to edit text for each sortable `<li>` elements text by ckeditor. But using the above code segment, inside text of the sortable item is not editable. 
I would like to both activity is that items should be drag-droppable and inline text editing.

How can I change the code segment which in a way sortable item text can be edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide an `id` attribute to your HTML tag, this probably to make sure that the library don't confuse your tag with other tags by mistake.

**Update**: the best way to have the implementation for this situation is to have the `sortable()` configured with disabled option, and upon `dbclick()` it will enable the inline editor and disable the sortable option, and on `blur()` we destroy the inline editor and re-enable sort functionality on the element.

I didn't test much enough so, you might encounter some errors related to the `blur()` being not triggered properly on the CKeditor, I will leave that to you. Just double click on editor `<li>` element this will enable CKeditor and then click inside it again to have the editor appearing, then you can click anywhere in the page to disable the editor and re-store the `sortable()` functionality.

here is a working snippet.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>

<p class="editor">Text edited by ckeditor outer sortable can edit by ckeditor</p>


<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight" id="editor">Text edited by ckeditor inside sortable can not edit by ckeditor</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<!-- <div id="editor">
    <p>this is test</p>
</div> -->
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/17.0.0/inline/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    $( function() {
      var myEditor;
        $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
          connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
          cancel: ".unsortable" 
        });

        document.querySelector( '#editor' ).addEventListener('dblclick', function() {
            $(this).addClass('unsortable');
            myEditor = InlineEditor
              .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
              .catch( error => {
                  console.error( error );
              }).then(editor => myEditor = editor)
        });

        document.querySelector( '#editor' ).addEventListener('blur', function() {
            myEditor.destroy().then(editor => $(this).removeClass('unsortable'))
        });
} );
  
</script>
```

Comment: Using the code segments, item can not be sortable with drag-drop, only inline text editor is active. I would like to both activity is that items should be drag-droppable and inline text editing.

Comment: I updated my snippet but seems like the events are overriding each other, will check it now, but would be a solution to have a button the toggle between sort-drag and edit?

Comment: Sorry I need both activity, item should be sortable and item text will be editable by ckeditor.

Comment: @OptimusPrime, I update my answer, please check it out.

Comment: Glad to help :)